# What are your favorite online forums in which Jewish links are posted?

Tags: discussion, meta

As [announced on lo.yodeya](http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/03/miyodeya-launch-party.html), we're going to launch into public beta on Rosh Chodesh Nissan 5770 (March 16, 2010). Basically, this means that we're going to start posting links to mi.yodeya in as many appropriate public places we can come up with. I'll be sure to post more details about how you can help on lo.yodeya when the launch gets closer.

Some obvious first choices for forums in which to promote mi.yodeya are represented by the sharing buttons that are currently hiding below the copyright notice on the right-hand column. (Those are going to be placed more prominently soon, by the way.) Where else should we go? Do you have favorite places online to find out about the latest Jewish web activity?

UPDATE: There's a running list of public places in which mi.yodeya's been mentioned [here](http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/03/miyodeya-is-now-public.html). I'm definitely still open to suggestions.

UPDATE 2: This question was posted when Judaism.SE's progenitor, mi.yodeya, was trying to build readership. It is at least as relevant now that Judaism.SE is trying to do the same thing on a larger scale. [Here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/what-blogs-have-linked-to-this-site) is a new list of blogs that have linked here.

Answer (score 1):

Put up a blog post about it (or ask some existing blogger to do so), and then submit this post to the blog carnival [Haveil Havalim](http://blogcarnival.com/bc/cprof_43.html).

Comment: Good idea! There will definitely be a lo.yodeya post, so at a minimum, I'll submit that. If anyone else blogs about us, we'll make sure those get submitted, too.

Comment: What about hirhurim?

Comment: Done and done. See http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/03/miyodeya-is-now-public.html.

Answer (score 1):

hirhurim is the best out there

Comment: Dave H, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your advice. The announcement I placed on Hirhurim has been the source of most of our new visitors since. Please consider clicking on "register," above, to create your account. This will give you access to all of mi.yodeya's features, and will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

The [Judaism sub-reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/) is a great place to exchange links about Jewish stuff. It has decent readership, a great commenting system, and a nice community.