# What blogs have linked to this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think it would be nice to maintain a list of blogs that have linked to judaism.SE / mi.yodeya, as a way to recognize our supporters and as a way to raise awareness that this is something we want to promote more of. I'll post a community-wiki answer, and I request that people add entries to the answer with a format like:

- **Name of blog(linked)** (username here if applicable (linked)) - Description of blog and of times it has linked to here, with links, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **[parshablog](http://parsha.blogspot.com/)** ([josh waxman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/458/josh-waxman)) - An extremely prolific and erudite blog about Torah commentary that features weekly roundups of online parsha resources, in-depth analyses of commentaries, and careful linguistic study. He is also an active member of our community, and he has re-used (with attribution!) [answers](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/05/why-trup-alternation-in-yisachar.html) he has [posted](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/01/karaites-and-naturally-occurring-manna.html) here as blog posts and as also featured content from here in [brief](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/08/interesting-posts-and-articles-325.html) "[interesting posts](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/05/interesting-posts-and-articles-313.html)" [roundups](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/03/interesting-posts-and-articles-308.html).
- **[The Rebbetzin's Husband](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/)** ([here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/59/the-rebbetzins-husband)) - Brings us behind the curtain, into the personal world of a pulpit (now kollel-head) rabbi who happens to be well-read, funny, and tech-savvy. He was generous enough to [support](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/03/shh-rabbis-coming.html) mi.yodeya when it first went public, and also pointed his readers here when he recycled an interesting [question](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-do-you-improve-your-kavvanah.html) from his blog into a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/how-do-you-improve-your-kavvanah-concentration) here as well.
- **[On The Contrary](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/)** ([ADDeRabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/54/adderabbi)) - It's hard to summarize this always-excellent rabbi blog except to point out that the author's username intentionally and fittingly incorporates "Attention Deficit Disorder," an Aramaic word for "on the contrary," "Rabbi," and a play on words. He was also generous enough to [support](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2010/03/reviews-and-recommendations-in-brief.html) mi.yodeya during its initial public launch.
- **[On the Main Line](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/)** (S.) - **Unique** and extensive research into a broad range of topics in Jewish history, anthropology, literature, Hebrew language and printing. Often focuses on lesser-known personalities or lesser-known sides of better-known ones. [Supported](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/03/miyodeya.html) mi.yodeya in its infancy.
- [**Twitter**](http://twitter.com)

  - (kristofclaes) - [2011 May 17](http://twitter.com/#!/kristofclaes/status/70385055838650368)
  - (wikitorah) - [2011 May 11](http://twitter.com/#!/wikitorah/status/68383203529986048)
  - (spolsky / [Joel Spolsky](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/503/joel-spolsky)) - [2011 May 9](http://twitter.com/#!/spolsky/status/67503838629859328) (honorable mention since his tweets and [blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/12/09.html) about our Area 51 proposal had a large role in getting us into the SE 2.0 network)
- [**Jew Square**](http://jewsquare.blogspot.com/) - [2011 May 13](http://jewsquare.blogspot.com/2011/05/stackoverflow-for-judaism.html)
- **[Monica's Journal](http://cellio.livejournal.com)** ([Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio)) took a fascinating [post](http://cellio.livejournal.com/884815.html) on her blog and converted it into a great [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/who-spoke-in-bamidbar-121) here, linking to the latter in the comments on the former.  Another time, she created an awesome [anthology](http://cellio.livejournal.com/891599.html) of science-fiction themed J.SE questions. Another time, a discussion on meta prompted [this d'var torah on Shoftim](http://cellio.livejournal.com/895259.html), with a link to the main site.  Also linked [2011-06-23](http://cellio.livejournal.com/886229.html), [2011-07-28](http://cellio.livejournal.com/890812.html), and other times since then that I've forgotten to mention.
- **[Al Pi Cheshbon](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com)** - A very interesting blog devoted to analyzing mathematical and numerical issues that come up in Judaism. Cited J.SE's [analysis](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com/2011/07/least-frequent.html) of Haftara frequency in a [post](http://cheshbon.weeklyshtikle.com/2011/07/least-frequent.html) on that topic.
- [**Torah Ideals**](http://torahideals.com/) – [a post just to link here, 2011 July 24](http://torahideals.com/2011/07/24/jewish-life-and-learning/)
- [**My Orthodox Life**](http://myorthodoxlife.com) ([TK Kocheran](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/545/tk-kocheran)) credited material from a comment [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/melacha-on-shabbat-at-which-stage-of-removal-does-something-become-legal/8413#8413) in his [post](http://myorthodoxlife.com/p/84/vegetarianism-and-halacha/) on "Vegetarianism and Halacha."
- Part of the [ingathering contest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/ingathering-contest-promote-your-favorite-question-and-win-our-prize):

  - [Monica linked to two contest questions (and one other)](http://cellio.livejournal.com/896663.html)
- **[Halocho a Day](http://halocho.blogspot.co.il/)** ([doniels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/501/danny-schoemann)) - A short Halacha - 5 days a week - from the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (usually). Started in 2007 and mirrored as a group on [FaceBook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/Halocho/). Mi Yodea is linked in the sidebar of each page under *Useful Halachic links*.

  - **[Mitzvah a Day](http://mitzvoh.blogspot.co.il/)** ([doniels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/501/danny-schoemann)) -  A blog listing all 77 positive and 194 negative Mitzvot that are applicable nowadays. Mi Yodea is linked in the sidebar of each page under *Useful Halachic links*.
- **[Frugal and Kosher](http://www.kosherfrugal.com/)** ([Scimonster](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5151/scimonster)) -  A blog that shares thoughts about being simultaneously frugal and kosher, as well as thoughts on making Aliyah. Promoted [*Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?*](http://s.tk/miyodeya) in a dedicated [post](http://www.kosherfrugal.com/2014/12/promotion-chanukah-q-from-mi-yodeya.html).
- [**Rationalist Judaism**](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2016/02/guest-post-mi-yodeya.html) - [R Natan Slifkin](http://www.zootorah.com/about/zoorabbi)'s blog exploring the legacy of the rationalist medieval Torah scholars, animals in Torah and various other topics. Published a guest post discussed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/a-model-my-guest-post-to-be-posted-on-blogs) on meta

Comment: @Monica - I'm really excited about the interaction we've already had with your blog, with a [post](http://cellio.livejournal.com/884815.html) from there turning into a great [question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/who-spoke-in-bamidbar-121) here. Any chance we could impose upon you for an overt endorsement?

Comment: good point -- I did pitch this during commitment, but now that we're in beta I should do so again and link to some interesting questions.  (Tomorrow is daf yomi day at my journal, so if you've got suggestions for questions that would tie in well on that post specifically, fire away.)

Comment: @Monica, Thanks for the pitch during commitment. Feel free to add a link to that into your bullet point here. I'm sure that if you keep this in mind, it won't be long before something here sparks your imagination enough to inspire a blog post or connect with something you were already going to write.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see us listed on http://jrants.com/

Go to http://jrants.com/blogs/add to submit an addition request.

Comment: http://jrants.com/blogs/add seems to be for requesting a link to a blog, which latter this is not. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't think they differentiate between personal blogs, newspaper blogs (jpost is on there) or wikis. Granted, I don't think they have any wikis linked, but I don't think they would discriminate.

Comment: thanks for the idea! I just tried to submit this site and got "You've already submitted a blog feed matching that information," so I guess someone has already submitted J.SE.

Comment: Hmm. It wasn't I. But that's good, I guess!