# Score chart and final results for the Ingathering Contest

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ingathering-contest

#### Final results:

October 3, 2011 15:30 pm

- **[Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio)  / [Still be slaves](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/if-god-had-not-delivered-us-from-egypt-we-would-still-be-slaves-really) - 295 (WINNER)**
- [Ariel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/369/ariel-k) / [E-reader erasure](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/is-it-permissible-to-erase-the-name-of-g-d-from-an-e-reader) - 191
- [Ezi](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/878/ezi) / [Credit card tzedaka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9929/878) - 91
- [Tal Fishman](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/766/tal-fishman) / [Market fairness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9467/766) - 56
- [Alex](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37/alex) / [Tefilin outreach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/putting-tefillin-on-un-educated-jews) - 37

Thanks very much to our winner, Monica Cellio, and to all of the other contestants for everything they did to promote our excellent Jewish Q&A content!

---

I've started an ongoing [score chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah3X9RC7ZLVodFJUVU54M0xLVFUxSVVJOFBxUVZnYWc&hl=en_US&pli=1#gid=0) for the [Ingathering Contest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/ingathering-contest-promote-your-favorite-question-and-win-our-prize).

I won't necessarily update this every day. If anyone is interested in helping keep it updated, please let me know.

This image will automatically stay up to date with the chart:
[image: Ingathering Contest Score Chart]

Comment: +1 Cool! Good use of Google gadgets.

Comment: I guess the "submit-new-question" strategy worked.

Comment: @Ariel, yes, for a good head-start, but the contest is yet young ...

Comment: @Ariel, I decided to try it to see what would happen because nobody else had.  I wasn't actually planning to enter, but 20 minutes before the start I thought of a question to try.  But by tomorrow it'll likely be off the front page and that'll change everything, I suspect.

Comment: Its OK, this isn't the highest stake contest and everyone could have picked a recent one also.

Comment: I think it will be interesting to see how the different approaches play out.  Day 3 of a 3-week contest is way too early to draw conclusions.  (Pity nobody picked a question specific to this season to see how that would work.)

Comment: @Monica, while the initial results are largely dependent on which question you each chose to bet on, I'm hoping that at least some of you will do some actual ingathering via social networking, blogging (as I know you've already done), seeding your favorite celebrity twitterer, etc., with effects that dominate the question-selection effects.

Comment: A lesson learned so far for me: I find it very difficult to ask people to go look at my own stuff (a question, in this case); I find it much easier to pitch the site in general or specific questions from other people, both of which I've done before.  I wonder if it's just me or if others are having this difficulty too.  (Also I seem to not be very good at it; mentions in my blog and G+ don't seem to have brought a lot of traffic, and a mailing list I also tried to use seems to be down at the moment. :-( )

Answer (score 2):

```
=(IF(RANK(C1,C1:C5)=2,C1,IF(RANK(C2,C1:C5)=2,C2,IF(RANK(C3,C1:C5)=2,C3,IF(RANK(C4,C1:C5)=2,C4,IF(RANK(C5,C1:C5)=2,C5,0))))))/MAX(C1:C5)
```

(Works in Excel 2008 for Mac; I don't know about Google Docs.) This finds the percentage of the top score the second-highest score is, where `C1` to `C5` are the scores at any point in time.