# Linking Mi Yodeya better with other great Judaism sites/blogs

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is a followup to my meta post [A newbie perspective after 60 days and 90 Q&As](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/a-newbie-perspective-after-60-days-and-90-qas/3876#3876) where I wrote

> If one agrees that the quality/interest of a site like MY is a
>   function of how many interesting and knowledgeable people contribute
>   then one would have an interest to increase that number. **It raises the question of how to
>   raise the site awareness amonst its target audience?**

I was thinking for instance of better linkages with great Jewish blogs that might attract similar audiences. Bloggers are always hungry for great content to republish, maybe we could send them our best questions on a regular/semi regular basis as a way to raise MY awareness amongst their readership.

**The goal of this post is to establish a list of relevant blogs one should contact to see if there are ways to strengthen the link with Mi Yodeya and get them to regularly re publish some interesting content.** I will b'n take on the first three as a beta test, and share results back here

1. [Torah Musings](http://www.torahmusings.com/)
2. [Rationalist Judaism](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/) (R Slifkin) [***has agreed to a guest post***](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/is-there-a-best-practice-my-guest-post-to-be-posted-on-blogs)
3. [Beyond BT](http://www.beyondbt.com/)
4. [Seforim](http://seforim.blogspot.co.il/)
5. **Others?**

And any you would pick [from this older list?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/what-blogs-have-linked-to-this-site)

Comment: Another list, but not of blogs: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/304/what-jewish-print-periodicals-do-you-read